# facebook FB.ui feed dialog customize option not working

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app which has feed dialog link. on Clicking the link the feed dialog opens up. I try to customize the friends who shall be able see the wallpost. This opens up the custom privacy dialog, but closes the feed dialog. So I cannot move forward with the wall post.

This happens when:
The app is being used as a page tab AND
The display mode is iframe.

This does not happens if:
The app is being used as an app (apps.facebook.com/app_name) OR
The display mode is popup.

Please advice...

Comment: This is hard to debug without more details on exactly what functions you are calling.  It might be that the functions you are using don't support XFBML or function differently.

Answer (score 0):

there is currently a bug in facebooks feed dialogs and the privacy dropdown... facebook *should* sort this out soon. In addition, you should [report this issue here.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)